# The motivation behind the definition of differentiablility of multivariable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

let $f$ be a function of one variable, we say that $f$ is differentiable, if there exists a number $a$ and a function $g(h)$, such that $$\cases{f(x+h)-f(x)=ah+|h|g(h) \\ \lim_{h\to 0}g(h)=0}$$

The author of my book said that the definition of differentiability for multivariable function, should be like this: let $f$ be a function defined on an open set $U$, $X\in U$ and $H$ is a vector s.t. $\|H\|$ is small enough so that $X+H\in U$. We say that $f$ is differentiable in $X$ if there exists a vector $A$ and a function $g(H)$, s.t.
$$\cases{f(X+H)-f(X)=A\cdot H+\|H\| g(H) \\ \lim_{H\to O}g(H)=0}$$
But I don't know how could the definition of differentiability for one variable function imply this? It's obvious that there is some kind of similarity between them, but I can't fully relate, especially why the author replace the absolute value with the magnitude of the vector?

Comment: The absolute value in one variable is the "size" of the displacement. In multivariable this should be measured in terms of the magnitude. The one variable definition doesn't exactly imply the multivariable one; you might expect from one variable that a multivariate function is differentiable if all its partial derivatives exist. But this turns out to not be good enough for a lot of routine computations.

Comment: The fundamental strategy of calculus is to take a nonlinear function $f$ (difficult) and approximate it locally by a linear function (easy). More explicitly, this approximation can be written as $f(x) \approx f(a) + f'(a)(x - a)$. The error in the approximation is $r(x) = f(x) - f(a) - f'(a)(x-a)$. The equation $\lim_{x \to a} \| r(x) \|/ \| x - a \| = 0$ tells us that the error in the approximation is small when $x$ is close to $a$. (In fact, the error is small even when when compared to $\|x-a \|$.)